# Observer pattern in wxPython

Tags: multithreading, wxpython, observer-pattern, ioerror

I am trying to implement the Observer design pattern with wxPython.
I have a modelling application that computes vast amount of data in the background. Sometimes I would like to display the output of the model in the GUI---which is just a grid of squares of different colours. Other times I need to do the computation without displaying the GUI.

The advantage of the observer pattern is that you can plug in or not a GUI just by adding or removing one line of code, something like

```
self.observers.append(MyWxGui())
```

or similar.
Now, to do that I need my computation to run on one thread, and the wx GUI to run in a different one.
I tried doing this with wxPython but I always get a Fatal I/O error:

```
python: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.0.
```

I read tutorials on multithreading in wxPython, such as http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks, but they all have the Mainloop() running in the main thread and than the long running task in a secondary thread, while I need it to be the other way round. This is because if I have the Mainloop() in the main thread, the program hangs waiting for some event from the GUI, instead of proceeding with the computation.

I also saw that I cannot manipulate Device contexts (DCs) such as ClientDC or PaintDC in a sub-thread, but I'm running the entire wx code inside the same thread.

Can the Mainloop() and all the wx GUI be run in its own thread that is not the main application's one?

Running wxPython 2.8.11.0 on Ubuntu 10.10 maverick.

Comment: Do you know a (non-threaded) implementation of the observer pattern in (wx)python? Pubsub, as mentioned below, is the global publisher-subscriber thing, and I did not yet find an observer pattern implemented.

Answer (score 3):

If you read that wiki page, then you should know that you can communicate back to the wx thread using wx.CallAfter, wxCallLater or wx.PostEvent in a thread-safe manner. I have a simple tutorial here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Personally, I would use something like Pubsub + one of the threadsafe methods mentioned above to communicate with the wx MainLoop. The nice thing about Pubsub is that it can listen for messages and react to them appropriately. The example above actually shows one way to do just that. Hopefully that will help you. Otherwise, I highly recommend joining the wxPython mailing list and asking there: http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/topics?pli=1

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. With CallAfter and sim. it is still the GUI that calls the model to continue processing once it's started. My target is to fully implement the Observer pattern, and therefore to have the model running entirely without the GUI. Consider for example if the GUI was disabled (i.e. the user decides to run the program with no GUI): how would the model continue if it's waiting for the GUI to issue the command called by CallAfter? The model would have to be aware that there is, potentially, a GUI, which defeats the observer idea.

Comment: Pubsub works outside of wx, so I think it would work for this. Or I'm misunderstanding something.